# pandas fillna is not working on subset of the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I want to impute the missing values for `df['box_office_revenue']` with the median specified by `df['release_date'] == x` and `df['genre'] == y` .

Here is my median finder function below.

```
def find_median(df, year, genre, col_year, col_rev):
   median = df[(df[col_year] == year) & (df[col_rev].notnull()) & (df[genre] > 0)][col_rev].median()
return median
```

The median function works. I checked. I did the code below since I was getting some CopyValue error.

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
```

I then go through the years and genres, `col_name = ['is_drama', 'is_horror', etc]` .

```
i = df['release_year'].min()
while (i < df['release_year'].max()):
for genre in col_name:
    median = find_median(df, i, genre, 'release_year', 'box_office_revenue')
    df[(df['release_year'] == i) & (df[genre] > 0)]['box_office_revenue'].fillna(median, inplace=True)
print(i)
i += 1
```

However, nothing changed!

```
len(df['box_office_revenue'].isnull())
```

The output was 35527. Meaning none of the null values in `df['box_office_revenue']` had been filled.

Where did I go wrong?

Here is a quick look at the data: The other columns are just binary variables

[image]

Comment: Can you give us some sample data to play with?

Comment: @DemetriP I just uploaded some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not elegant, but I think it works.  Basically, I calculate the means conditioned on genre and year, and then join the data to a dataframe containing the imputing values.  Then, wherever the revenue data is null, replace the null with the imputed value

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Fake Data
rev = np.random.normal(size = 10_000,loc = 20)
rev_ix = np.random.choice(range(rev.size), size = 100 )
rev[rev_ix] = np.NaN
year = np.random.choice(range(1950,2018), replace = True, size = 10_000)
genre = np.random.choice(list('abc'), size = 10_000, replace = True)




df = pd.DataFrame({'rev':rev,'year':year,'genre':genre})
imputing_vals = df.groupby(['year','genre']).mean()


s = df.set_index(['year','genre'])
s.rev.isnull().any() #True

#Creates dataframe with new column containing the means
s = s.join(imputing_vals, rsuffix = '_R')

s.loc[s.rev.isnull(),'rev'] = s.loc[s.rev.isnull(),'rev_R']
new_df = s['rev'].reset_index()
new_df.rev.isnull().any() #False
```

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned

> I did the code below since I was getting some CopyValue error...

The warning is important.  You did not give your data, so I cannot actually check, but the problem is likely due to:

```
df[(df['release_year'] == i) & (df[genre] > 0)]['box_office_revenue'].fillna(..)
```

Let's break this down:

First you select some rows with:

```
df[(df['release_year'] == i) & (df[genre] > 0)]
```

Then from that, you select a columns with:

```
...['box_office_revenue']
```

And now you have a problem...

#### Why?

The problem is that when you selected some rows (ie: not all), pandas was forced to create a copy of your dataframe.  You then select a column of the *copy*!.  Then you `fillna()` on the copy.  Not super useful.

#### How do I fix it?

Select the column first:

```
df['box_office_revenue'][(df['release_year'] == i) & (df[genre] > 0)].fillna(..)
```

By selecting the entire column first, pandas is not forced to make a copy, and thus subsequent operations should work as desired.

Comment: I did the proposed change then restarted the kernel, but nothing changed.

Comment: That is certainly possible.  So, give us some data to work with.  And NO, pictures of data don't count.

Comment: Okay, so one thing I noticed was that my `find_median(...)` works but when it's put in that loop the `median = nan` . Also, do you want me to create a sample of my data and upload it?

Comment: Yes Always on the Data....  Pandas question are very well followed.  But without easily copy and pastable data, it can be a struggle, and thus you will get fewer answers.

Answer (score 0):

This URL describing *chained assignments* seems useful for such a case: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters

As seen in above URL:
[image]

Hence, instead of doing (in your 'for' loop):

```py
for genre in col_name:
    median = find_median(df, i, genre, 'release_year', 'box_office_revenue')
    df[(df['release_year'] == i) & (df[genre] > 0)]['box_office_revenue'].fillna(median, inplace=True)
```

You can try:

```py
for genre in col_name:
    median = find_median(df, i, genre, 'release_year', 'box_office_revenue')
    df.loc[(df['release_year'] == i) & (df[genre] > 0) & (df['box_office_revenue'].isnull()), 'box_office_revenue'] = median
```